# How to optimize a painting algorithm of graph with big amount of points?

Tags: algorithm, qt, plot, graph, graphics

I have a simple plotter module written with Qt that just paint a graph based on vector of points.

It works well but it starts to have problems with performance when there are hundreds of thousands points.

The algorithm of painting is primitive - just adding points in for statement to a `QPolygonF` and painting a polyline afterwards. Pseudocode:

```
for (visiblePartOfPointsOnScreen, step = 1)
    polyline.append(getPointFromSource)

drawPolyline(polyline)
```

Large amount of points (100k eg) can't be displayed on the screen at all (1 point - 1 pixel). Therefore, for example, sin graph would look like a rectange if it were zoomed out. According to the fact we can't display all these points, I'm looking for the way to optimize the process - not to draw unnecessary (not visible on this scale) points but save the correct shape of zoomed graph.

I did kind of an optimization - depending on an amount of points on the screen (if it's too big), i skip several points, that is, `step` becomes more than 1. Optimization worked out, speed of painting was increased, but it caused graphic artifacts while moving or scaling graphs.

Could you please tell me what the best way to optimize painting of a lot of points?

Comment: you could try to paint them on a QPixmap when adding points to the graph, possibly in another thread

Comment: @Amfasis I draw it in QQuickPaintedItem into the paint method. I'm not sure painting on QPixmap can speed it up.

Comment: You mean that the sheer number of visible points is too much, if all are painted? You will have to provide a bit more of info if we shall help you, otherwise the simple recommendation "paint until acceptable time is up then stop" is the only valid answer.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Have refined the question for you.